# Getting an error message under PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, ant

[image]

PhoneGap is latest at 3.4.0 and the Android SDK was also updated to the latest ones just a couple of hours ago.

I also installed Apache Ant and put the bin directory of Apache Ant under my PATH variable.

What does this error message mean?  I tried to google for "code 8" but I did not get any clear answers.

You can save the above image or open the image in a new tab if you want to read the error message more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run dirrectly the command

```
%userprofile%\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\check_reqs.bat
```

it should display a clearer message about the error.

It seems either you haven't installed android sdk manager, or haven't added it to the path or haven't downloaded the sdk for API 19.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The check_reqs.bat gives me only one line which is An error occured while listing Android targets.

And I already stated at the beginning of the thread but, the Android SDK was updated to the latest only a couple of hours 

http://magician.sdf-eu.org/files/attempt2.jpg

Comment: You accepted the answer, does it mean it's ok now? If not ok, check that if you run `android` in a command prompt it starts the sdk manager.